# Missing Stack Exchange OpenID option at data.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid, data-explorer, login

I wanted to log in to the Stack Exchange data explorer, but I found out that the [login page](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login) does not list the SE's own OpenID login as option (manually entering the SE's OpenID URL worked).

[image]

Comment: Should you want this sooner rather than later, feel free to [submit a patch](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer). :)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. It's no big deal as far as I'm concerned, I just thought I'd mention the inconsistency. But thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: No problem. It's inconsistent because the SEDE codebase is completely independent of the SE codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

waffles may decide it makes more sense to just update based on the Stack Exchange source, but if not I've gone ahead and [added this option](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=957716717504b696c80e1fe21d65ea7afa7d79a5) along with some other OpenID-related tweaks.

Comment: If it's deployed within 7 days the full bounty is yours :)

Comment: @ChrisF done ...... also, thanks Tim

Comment: @canon I've been a bit tied up with work, but I'm in the middle of adding various OAuth login options to Data Explorer, so Facebook will be added then. I don't have a firm estimation of when it'll be done, but hopefully it'll be pretty soon.