# StackExchange OpenID provider not an option on Careers site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, user-interface, openid

I noticed that the StackExchange OpenID provider isn't listed as an option on the Careers 2.0 website. It is an option on the family of SE sites (with the AOL option being replaced with a smaller logo), but the Careers site doesn't appear to share the same options. I thought I would point this out for consistency's sake.

**Careers:**

[image: Careers OpenID missing StackExchange provider]

**All other sites:**

[image: OpenID options on SE family sites]

**EDIT:** I found another question that indicates the same issue occurs on the Data Explorer site: [Missing openid option at data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96330/missing-openid-option-at-data-stackexchange-com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We’ve implemented this. It doesn’t have exactly the same ajaxy goodness as on other Stack sites, but works fine.

Answer (score 4):

We haven't gotten around to implementing it yet, but will (time-frame tbd). In the mean time, if you have an SE OpenID that you want to use, you should be able to do so by entering the URL (click on "more OpenID options").