# Why log-in functionality using Facebook isn't available at data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**

> [Missing openid option at data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96330/missing-openid-option-at-data-stackexchange-com)

Why there is no log-in functionality using Facebook available at [Data Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login), but available at other network sites?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Missing Stack Exchange OpenID option at data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96330/286110) because nothing related to Facebook OpenID is mentioned in the question, or in the answer.

This question needs to be addressed specifically.

Comment: Readers: Is there a way I can ask to re-open this question?

Comment: @Firelord the edit bumped this question to reopen review queue, so there's nothing you have to do other than wait for the result of the review.

Comment: @AndrewT. Now that four days has been passed, should I now take it as the request is been denied to re-open this question? In fact, how do I even check it since I can't access any review queue because of not having the required privilege?