# Can the Stack Exchange OpenID button be added to the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, openid, data-explorer, login, stack-exchange-openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Missing OpenID option at data.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96330/missing-openid-option-at-data-stackexchange-com)

[image: Stack Exchange Data Explorer login screen]

The [Data Explorer Login screen](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login) currently does't have the Stack Exchange OpenID button/link like other SE sites. It would be great to have it added!